# Git sync without commit

Tags: git, kubernetes, gitops

We are using atlassian git for Gitops deployment. The agent running in kubernetes cluster frequently check commits or changes in the master branch and deploy it accordingly. Last time our git was down, and we made changes in the production cluster manually. Now I am looking for an option to sync the changes which performed from my local git repository to the organization repository (Production), does anybody know is there a way to do this? If I commit the change then the Gitops will re-deploy the changes to the production and I don't want that.

Comment: if you commit a change that is already applied in production leads to your gitops tool to lead to a redeployment, it is most likely configured wrong. it should continously detect drift between desired and actual state and only act if something needs to be done. I am actually suprised that it does not revert your manual changes in production as it is not in sync with your git repository

Comment: The gitops will redeploy the changes only, if I perform a forceful sync.

Comment: How exactly the agent is configured on the cluster? How K8s cluster environment is set up - version, bare-metal/cloud?